# strange shape of the boxplot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

```
data= np.array([9,13,10,9,13,5,13,9,7,9,13,11])
fig9, ax9 = plt.subplots()
ax9.boxplot(data, notch=True)
```

I got the strange the notched boxplot. I want to use the notch to highlight the median.
Why this figure showed the strange shape? Is this not strange?

[image]

I use MacOS 10.14.5 and python 3.7.2.

Comment: I used matplotlib 3.0.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's explained quite clearly in the [boxplot documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html). The note states:

**Note:**
In cases where the values of the CI are less than the lower quartile or greater than the upper quartile, the notches will extend beyond the box, giving it a distinctive "flipped" appearance. This is expected behavior and consistent with other statistical visualization packages.

So if you calculate the params you will see that you are en the described case.

```
>>> [np.quantile(data, i) for i in np.arange(0.25, 1, 0.25)]
[9.0, 9.5, 13.0]
>>> scipy.stats as st
>>> st.t.interval(0.95, len(data)-1, loc=np.mean(data), scale=st.sem(data))
(8.425200299187184, 11.741466367479484)
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. I'm ashamed that I couldn't understand the Note. I understood that I cannot draw the figure I was expected.

Comment: No shame in that - I always forget that CI is short for confidence interval and as such a looooot of things don't make sense xD